# How to customize sidebartab highlighted section

Tags: beamer, themes

I’m preparing a presentation with the following theme:

```
\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=3cm,left]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove,sidebartab}
```

I would like to change the font color of the highlighted section/subsection and also to make it bold:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=3cm,left]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove,sidebartab}

\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=white, bg=black}
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\section{Subsection 1.1}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Subsection 1.2}

\section{Section 2}

\section{Subsection 2.1}

\section{Subsection 2.2}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Unfortunatelly, `\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{series=\bfseries}` makes every section/subsection bold, not just the highlighted one.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to modify `\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=blue, bg=red}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=3cm,left]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove,sidebartab}

\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=blue, bg=red}



\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{testtest}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to change the font back to non-bold, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=3cm,left]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove,sidebartab}

%Colours
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=blue, bg=red}

% Fonts
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar shaded}{series=\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar shaded}{\usebeamerfont{section in sidebar shaded}\insertsectionhead}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 


\section{Subsection 1.1}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Subsection 1.2}

\section{Section 2}

\section{Subsection 2.1}

\section{Subsection 2.2}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. However, `\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{series=\bfseries}` makes every section bold, not just the current one.

Comment: Curiously, the bakground color of the current subsection is also changed, but not its foreground color.

Comment: @metalfox If you would make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem, I could have a look into that.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @metalfox For the font issue, please see my edit. As for the colour change of the current subsection, I get both the foreground and background colour changed? Can you elaborate what you want the subsections to have colour wise?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it in a MWE, yet it happens on my presentation :-(. I think I won't use sidebartab at all and instead get the effect with `section in sidebar` and `section in sidebar shaded`. For curiosity, how did you figure out the hack in `section in sidebar shaded`? I'm really impressed. BTW, thanks so much.

Comment: @metalfox For the subsection colours, have you tried to explicitly set the colour to what you want them to have? How to figure out this hack: I searched the source code for `section in sidebar` and it turned out that the font for section in sidebar was applied before the shaded and non-shaded templates were called - so I had to somehow add the font for the shaded template and redefining the template was way easier then redefining the whole naviagtion thingy where the fonts are normally called - in summary: with a little bit of beamer experience :)